# Crystal Reports with VS 2010 login prompt

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports with Visual Studio 2010 and connecting to an Access db that **requires no login or password**.  I am using Report Viewer to show drop-down boxes in order to filter data from 3 tables.  It was working okay when I ran it previously, but now when I run it I am shown a database login window asking for user name and password.  I have tried to clear the fields and continue, but this does not help.  I saw that other users had this problem, but their databases required user and passwords and mine doesn't.  Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: could you provide your code? do you know what changed between now and when it was previously working?